# Is it possible to calculate width of particular line in Javacv or opencv?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I'm doing project which use image processing techniques and I used javacv package as a interface to call opencv methods. And I like to know how to identify line might have two curve on both sides(As shows in bellow image). This image is drown with particular scale. So if i can calculate the width of that line its possible to calculate actual width.

[image]

In above image I need to calculate total length (pink color strait not the dash line)
Please can some one share your experience to identify and calculate this kind of line width using javacv or opencv.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will have to find only points of the straight line.
 Maybe you can do this using morphology operators. Then, you can use [cvContours](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) to get a list of points your line.

The [arcLength](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#arclength) function gives you the line's length.

Comment: Can you please give some simple opencv or javacv code for that ?